# Placeholder em <h:inputText com JSF 1.x

Tags: jsf, placeholder, rich-faces

Bom dia,

Eu estou com um sistema desenvolvido com a versão 1.2 do JSF e RichFaces 3.3

Andei pesquisando sobre incluir um placeholder no elemento `<h:inputText` do jsf mas só encontrei tutoriais para a versão 2 do jsf ou primefaces. Também achei uma forma de fazer com o RichFaces, porém sómente da versão 4 em diante.
Não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

Alguém conhece uma forma de incluir um placeholder na tag `<h:inputText` ?
como num HTML normal:

```
<input value="item" placeholder="seach"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
<h:inputText value="item" placeholder="search" id="search"/>
<p:watermark for="search" value="Meu placeholder" />
```

Lembre-se de adicionar o atributo `id="nome"` no seu inputText, e na outra tag, você coloca o atributo `for` referenciando essa id, igual o exemplo acima.